# Ember reload array controller when item in array changes

Tags: arrays, ember.js, controller

I have an ArrayController in which I am showing 2 groups of objects filtered by 'group.'  When I edit a person, I can change their group using an Ember select and I can see the group changed in the list, but  the question is how do I notify the parent ArrayController that it needs to reapply the filters and re-render the {{#each}} blocks?

Here's a JSBin that shows the problem.  http://jsbin.com/ISIKAjOZ/5/edit

To see this in the JSBin, click on one of the people and change their group using the drop down.  You'll see their group number update, but they need to move from one list to the other...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the dependency (in the property) should tell ember what to watch to know when the property is dirty and should be recalculated.

```
  group1:function() {
    return this.get("content").reduce(function (arr, object, index) {
      if(object.get("group") === 1) {
        arr.pushObject(object);
      }
      return arr;
    }, Em.A());
  }.property("content.@each.group"),
```

http://jsbin.com/iBaCOrOt/1/edit

http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

By the way

```
  group1:function() {
    return this.get("content").filterBy('group', 1);
  }.property("content.@each.group"),
```

Comment: Perfect!  Didn't know you could add '@each' like that in the property.  I have to wait 7 minutes before I can give you the check mark.  :)

Comment: Note that @each only works one level deep. You cannot use nested forms like todos.@each.owner.name or todos.@each.owner.@each.name.

Comment: Oh and filterBy is a super easy built in function to filter

Comment: sweet, didn't know about that either.  man you should just pull a chair up next to me :)

Comment: I'm back... do you know if you can use multiple @each in the same property?  for example: .property("todos.@each.name", "todos.@each.age")

Comment: yup, you also could enable the feature `propertyBraceExpansion` and do 'todos.@each.{name,age}', https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3538